# Data contract serialization for IList<T>

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I have the following code in which I'm trying to serialize a list to a file

```
public static void Serialize<T>(this IList<T> list, string fileName)  
{
   try
   {
      var ds = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
      using (Stream s = File.Create(fileName))
          ds.WriteObject(s, list);  
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      _logger.Error(e);
      throw;
   } 
}
```

and I'm getting the exception:

> Type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[**MyClass**,
>   **MyNameSpace**, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]' with data contract name
>   'ArrayOf**MyClass**:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/**MyNameSpace**'
>   is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any
>   types not known statically to the list of known types - for example,
>   by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the
>   list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

```
[KnownType(typeof(MyClass))]
[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
    #region Properties
    [DataMember]
    public string Foo{ set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Bar{ set; get; }
}
```

Any ideas?

There is no inheritance.

Comment: shouldn't you be doing new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<T>)) or something similar

Comment: good catch. can u write that as response so i can mark it. Thanks,

Comment: no problem, done the same thing before :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What has happened is that the serializer is expecting an instance of T, not a list of T, so you want your method to be like so:

```
public static void Serialize<T>(this IList<T> list, string fileName)  
{
   try
   {
      var ds = new DataContractSerializer(list.GetType());
      using (Stream s = File.Create(fileName))
        ds.WriteObject(s, list);  
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
     _logger.Error(e);
     throw;
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, the serializer should be for the list, not the type of items.

Additionally, `[KnownType(typeof(MyClass))]` should take a class inheriting from MyClass in parameter, not MyClass itself.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

> var ds = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T[]));